# How can i convert character 0s and 1s read from a txt File to byte?

Tags: java, text-files

I want to read a txt file containing 0s and 1s , and convert them to bytes but first convert to binary. e.g textFile contains "00101001". Every character is 1 byte , after reading from file i get 8 bytes. Now i want to append them to a String and convert to byte. I should get 1 byte from 8 bytes.Is that right?

is there is a better option?.
What i have did so far:

```
public byte[] convertBytes(String File1, int length) throws IOException
{

    byte BytesfromFile[]=readInput(File1,length);          // readinput() returns (length*8) bytes,contains 48 or 49s.
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();             //Stringbuilder append chars to build String
    byte convertedBytes[]=new byte[BytesfromFile.length/8];            //size of byte array init
    int stringToInt;
    byte intToByte;

    for(int index=0,bitcounter=0,indexCoverted=0;index<BytesfromFile.length;index++,++bitcounter)
    {

        stringBuilder.append((char) BytesfromFile[index]); //append 48 or 49 casted to char

        if(bitcounter==8)
        {   String Binary = stringBuilder.toString();   // if 8 bits appended, toString
            stringToInt = Integer.parseInt(Binary, 2);  // convert Binary String to Int
            intToByte = (byte)stringToInt;              // cast Int to byte
            convertedBytes[indexCoverted++]=intToByte;
            bitcounter=0;
            stringBuilder.setLength(0);                 //set length to 0, to append next 8 bit.
        }
    }
            return convertedBytes;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *I should get 1 byte from 64 bytes*?

Comment: I read from text file 8 characters. "10101001". Every one is actually 1 byte , e.g. the first character is 1 in byte it is 49. 49 in binary is 00110001. But i dont want to convert the 49 , i want the character 0 as single bit in byte.

Comment: So you should get 8 bytes from a file of 64 bytes, not 1 byte. Isn't it?

Comment: 1 byte from file give me 1 bit, yes u are right . My mistake. i meant 64 bit :D. or better 1 byte from 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Byte.parseByte` method with a radix of 2:

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte(str, 2);
```

You can alternatively use the `BigInteger(String val,int radix)` constructor to quickly do the conversion on a long `String` of binary digits:

```
String input = "1010010010010101010010010101001";
byte[] arr = new BigInteger(input, 2).toByteArray();

// Result:
// [82, 74, -92, -87]
```

Comment: u mean i can convert my String directly to byte, instead of casting it first to int?

Comment: Yep: no need to explicitly cast to `int`. For example, `Byte.parseByte("1010", 2)` returns 10.